# How to retrieve google search results legitimately, can you do this with custom search engine?

Tags: google-api, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I need to retrieve google search results for about 200 phrases per day, legitimately through google's systems. I am using php and have been using googles old web search api: https://developers.google.com/web-search/ though as it clearly states it is now officially deprecated. They want users to move across to the "Custom Search Engine API", which I have signed up to be billed for does not do the same thing, it won't run without a cx parameter, meaning you REQUIRE a custom search engine, which you cannot (any more) set to show google results.

Is there a legitimate way to query google for results any more or am I stranded using the existing API up to its 100 query limit per day until they switch it off?

Comment: Custom Search Engine API returns list of urls in xml format aswell, so you might fetch urls from that xml file and show it on your web page. I know it's not a proper way to do but they have tied our hands... or maybe i am wrong and i don't know way to do it.

Comment: That's not really related to my question